# How to safely wrap win32's PSTR or PWSTR in an Option type (e.g. Option<&OsStr>)?

Tags: windows, rust, ffi

I am trying to create a safe wrapper around some Win32 APIs using Microsoft's [windows crate](https://crates.io/crates/windows) like so:

```
use windows::{Win32::Foundation::*, Win32::System::Threading::*};

fn create_process(app_name: &std::ffi::OsStr) -> bool {
    let mut startup_info: STARTUPINFOW = unsafe { std::mem::zeroed() };
    startup_info.cb = std::mem::size_of::<STARTUPINFOW>() as u32;
    let mut process_info: PROCESS_INFORMATION = unsafe {std::mem::zeroed() };

    unsafe {
        let success = CreateProcessW(
            app_name,            // lpapplicationname
            None,                // lpcommandname
            std::ptr::null(),    // lpprocessattributes
            std::ptr::null(),    // lpthreadattributes
            true,                // binherithandles
            CREATE_SUSPENDED,    // dwcreationflags
            std::ptr::null(),    // lpenvironment
            &startup_info,       // lpstartupinfo
            &mut process_info    // lpprocessinformation
        ).as_bool();

        success
    }
}

fn main() {
    let app = std::ffi::OsStr::new("C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");
    let success = create_process(app);
    print!("{}", success);

}
```

This works as expected.

However, the [documentation for CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw#syntax) states that

> The lpApplicationName parameter can be NULL.

Thus, I would like to wrap the `&OsStr` in an `Option<&OsStr>` so I can use `None` when no lpApplicationName is needed.

But I cannot find a way to convert from `Option<&OsStr>` to anything that satisfies `IntoParam<'a, PWSTR>` for lpApplicationName.

Comment: Windows and Rust are not ever going to be Best Friends. As it stands, there is no string type in Rust that would represent a native Windows string. In this situation I would probably use the [`windows-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/windows-sys) crate instead, and provide a more capable (and compatible) custom string type at the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [#1801](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/pull/1081) `&OsStr` should implement `IntoParam<PWSTR>`. Since `null()` also implements it, you should be able to write:

```
use windows::core::{IntoParam, Param};

let app_name_param: Param<'_, PWSTR> = if let Some(app_name) = app_name {
    app_name.into_param()
} else {
    Param::None
};
```

...and pass `app_name_param` to `CreateProcessW`.

(I can't test this because I run on Linux, where `Foundation/mod.rs` fails to compile due to requiring `std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt`.)